# Pandas Dataframe add columns based on Date value

Tags: python, pandas

I have `df` like this

```
        Open      High       Low     Close     Volume                Date
3     25940.99  25972.27  25934.36  25938.65  176.08278 2023-08-23 02:20:00
4     25938.65  25938.65  25903.73  25921.67   67.24124 2023-08-23 02:25:00
5     25921.66  25963.83  25904.68  25951.51   83.37560 2023-08-23 02:30:00
6     25951.51  26011.07  25950.00  25998.00  119.22832 2023-08-23 02:35:00
7     25997.99  26050.50  25997.99  26015.14  242.94235 2023-08-23 02:40:00
```

Then i used resample `df` to 60 min - `df_resample`

```
                         Open      High       Low     Close      Volume
Date
2023-08-23 02:00:00  25940.99  26070.04  25903.73  26056.00  1055.06782
2023-08-23 03:00:00  26055.99  26187.99  26030.56  26040.38  2447.77226
2023-08-23 04:00:00  26040.38  26081.64  25994.12  26049.41   728.81260
2023-08-23 05:00:00  26049.41  26091.75  26033.00  26044.42   795.45411
2023-08-23 06:00:00  26044.41  26078.01  25990.15  26006.32   764.41941
```

How to insert new column `df_resample['High'] - df_resample['Low']` from `df_resample` to the `df`? Based on what hour the `Date` value is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can create temporary columns and then merge:

```py
df1["date"] = df1.Date.dt.date
df1["hour"] = df1.Date.dt.hour

df2["date"] = df2.index.date
df2["hour"] = df2.index.hour

df2["Value"] = df2["High"] - df2["Low"]

df1 = df1.merge(df2[["date", "hour", "Value"]], on=["date", "hour"]).drop(
    columns=["date", "hour"]
)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
       Open      High       Low     Close     Volume                Date   Value
0  25940.99  25972.27  25934.36  25938.65  176.08278 2023-08-23 02:20:00  166.31
1  25938.65  25938.65  25903.73  25921.67   67.24124 2023-08-23 02:25:00  166.31
2  25921.66  25963.83  25904.68  25951.51   83.37560 2023-08-23 02:30:00  166.31
3  25951.51  26011.07  25950.00  25998.00  119.22832 2023-08-23 02:35:00  166.31
4  25997.99  26050.50  25997.99  26015.14  242.94235 2023-08-23 02:40:00  166.31
```

Comment: can you tell me please, what to add to the condition if the second dataframe has a period of not an hour, but 30 minutes? How to understand that 5 10 15 20 25 minutes are in the first thirty minutes?